# How to get the correct numbered and unnumbered headings with automark from sections added automatically with tcolorbox and addcontentsline?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, koma-script, tcolorbox

I want to know if there is a way to get the correct section mark automatically when adding sections with `\addcontentsline` (wrapped into a `\newtcolorbox`).

I tried to add `\chead{#2}` in the title of the `\newtcolorbox` as well as adding it with the tcolorbox option `before=\chead{#2}`.

If I add `\chead{title}` before the `\newtcolorbox` it looks like I want it to do but I don't want to type every title twice.

```
\documentclass[
    fontsize=8pt
    , a5paper
    , ngerman
    , twocolumn
    , parskip=half
    , titlepage=firstiscover
    , fleqn
    ]{scrartcl}
%
\renewcommand{\coverpagetopmargin}{10mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpageleftmargin}{9mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpagerightmargin}{9mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpagebottommargin}{10mm}
%
% Preamble
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
    \addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}}
    \addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \tcbset{%
        enhanced
        , sharp corners
        , colback=white
        , colframe=black
        , boxrule=1pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
    locale=DE
    , display-per-mode=fraction
    , inline-per-mode=symbol
    ]{siunitx}
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
    \geometry{left=9mm, right=9mm}
%
% Titelseite
\title{Formelsammlung}
\author{Ich}
\date{\today}
%
\begin{document}
%
\maketitle
%
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
%
\clearpage
\onecolumn
%
\newtcolorbox[use counter*=section]{secbox}[2][]{adjusted title={\makebox[2em][l]{\thetcbcounter}#2}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\thesection}#2}, fonttitle=\sffamily, #1}
\newtcolorbox[]{secbox*}[2][]{adjusted title={#2}\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}, fonttitle=\sffamily, #1}
%
% \chead{Mathematische Grundlagen}
\begin{secbox}[]{Mathematische Grundlagen}
    $\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}
    \qquad c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
    \qquad a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}
    \qquad b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}
    \qquad \text{Satz des Pythagoras}$
    \end{secbox}
\begin{secbox*}[height fill]{Mathematische Grundlagen}
    $\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}
    \qquad c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
    \qquad a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}
    \qquad b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}
    \qquad \text{Satz des Pythagoras}$
    \end{secbox*}
%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but it seems to work:

```latex
\documentclass[
    fontsize=8pt
    , a5paper
    , ngerman
    , twocolumn
    , parskip=half
    , titlepage=firstiscover
    , fleqn
    ]{scrartcl}
%
\renewcommand{\coverpagetopmargin}{10mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpageleftmargin}{9mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpagerightmargin}{9mm}
\renewcommand{\coverpagebottommargin}{10mm}
%
% Preamble
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{babel}
    \addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tab.}}
    \addto{\captionsngerman}{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Abb.}}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \tcbset{%
        enhanced
        , sharp corners
        , colback=white
        , colframe=black
        , boxrule=1pt}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[%
    locale=DE
    , display-per-mode=fraction
    , inline-per-mode=symbol
    ]{siunitx}
\usepackage[hidelinks, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[]{geometry}
\geometry{left=9mm, right=9mm}

\newtcolorbox[use counter*=section,list inside={toc},list type={section}]{secbox}[2][]{code=\stepcounter{section}\sectionmark{#2}\addtocounter{section}{-1},adjusted title={\makebox[2em][l]{\thetcbcounter}#2},fonttitle=\sffamily,list text={#2},#1}

\newtcolorbox[list inside={toc},list type={section}]{secbox*}[2][]{code=\addsecmark{#2},adjusted title={#2},list entry={\nonumberline #2},fonttitle=\sffamily, #1}

% Titelseite
\title{Formelsammlung}
\author{Ich}
\date{\today}
%
\begin{document}
%
\maketitle
%
\clearpage
\twocolumn
\tableofcontents
%
\clearpage
\onecolumn
%
\begin{secbox}[]{Mathematische Grundlagen}
    $\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}
    \qquad c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
    \qquad a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}
    \qquad b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}
    \qquad \text{Satz des Pythagoras}$
  \end{secbox}

\clearpage
\begin{secbox*}[height fill]{Mathematische Grundlagen}
    $\boxed{a^2+b^2=c^2}
    \qquad c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}
    \qquad a=\sqrt{c^2-b^2}
    \qquad b=\sqrt{c^2-a^2}
    \qquad \text{Satz des Pythagoras}$
    \end{secbox*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, that I'm using the list feature of `tcolorbox` and also the `code` option. The `code` option is executed outside the box used by `tcolorbox` and therefore the mark generated by `\sectionmark` or `\addsecmark` is still valid after ending the `secbox` resp. `secbox*` environment.

Comment: This works well for me and the above example. For some reason in my final document I have to call `\chead{\leftmark}` once to get it but that is okay as well.

Comment: @SENTiNEL Maybe a missing `automark` option when loading `scrlayer-scrpage` or you are using `scrreprt` or `scrbook` instead of `scrartcl`. In this case `\automark[section]{section}` or `\automark*[section]{section}` could also help. But without MWE this is only a guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. As soon as I know more about it, I'll let you know - perhaps with a new example.

Comment: And thanks to @cabohah for your quick response.

Comment: It is caused by the `twoside` class option. Is there a solution for two-sided documents with the same mark on both sides?
I will customize the header and footer anyway and then use it document-wide, so the above solution is still effective.

Comment: @SENTiNEL See the `\automark` suggestion in my first comment. For more information about `\automark` see the user manual. If this does not help, please ask a [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117/277964).